# Pubnub AccessDeniedException . errorData=PNErrorData(information=null

Tags: pubnub

I am having issues with PubNub when subscribing. This is bit random. Works well 90% time on emulator. But fails most of the time on an actual device:

```
 var pubnub = new PubNub(pnConfiguration);
 addListener()
 pubnub.subscribe()
            .channels(Arrays.asList(pubnubChannelId))
            .execute();
```

Error :

```
PNStatus(category=PNAccessDeniedCategory, 
errorData=PNErrorData(information=null, 
throwable=com.pubnub.api.PubNubException), 
error=true, statusCode=403, 
operation=PNSubscribeOperation, tlsEnabled=true .....
```

I have enabled verbose logs in PubNub Configuration. I am at total loss trying to understand this error messages.

Where do I start debugging this ? same code works most of the time on emulator but on a physical device ?

appreciate any pointers.

Thanks

Comment: 403? you probably have Access Manager enabled and you are not granting read permissions to the client apps that are attempting to subscribe. Please check your key set in the PubNub Admin Console and disable Access Manager if it is enabled.

Comment: our server dev takes care of the console stuff. Server side provides us access keys so that client apps can connect. So, that isn't the issue.  Could this happen if. a user logs in on two different devices with same account ? I have a couple of test accounts that I keep rotating between 2 or 3 devices during feature development.

Comment: No, not as long as the device/client has an auth-key with proper permissions. I would enable logging in the PubNub SDK and send logs to us at support.pubnub.com

Comment: where are these logs you mention located ?

Comment: Please review this: https://www.pubnub.com/docs/android-java/pubnub-android-sdk-troubleshooting-guide. If you are using a different SDK, choose the appropriate SDK from the menu at the the top right of that page.

Comment: We are using AccessManager to pass authKey. Seems like - when authkey has a '+' sign in it, fails. The authKey is generated using a cryptography Library called libsodium. The PubNub SDK for Android is not encoding the URL as + is treated as a space when decoded and thus fails. Is this a known issue? What is the work around for this ? The issue doesn't repro on webclient with same authkey.

Comment: @CraigConover hi, did you get a chance to look at this issue?

Comment: There is fix for the Android SDK to fix this.

Comment: thanks a lot. Please let me know once the new sdk is posted. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

replacing the character + with another one is a workaround. Pubnub will post an official build soon.